# Get the source url of link by custom firefox MenuItem

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, contextmenu, menuitem, firefox-addon-sdk

I have tried to:

- Add menu item to the mozilla firefox menu,
- It should appear only if the user click on link ,
- If the user click on the menuItem, the source url will be looged in the console.

that is my code , which fail to show menu item at all :

```
 var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
 var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
                              label         : "Show the url",
                              context       : contextMenu.SelectorContext("a[href]"), 
                              contentScript : 'self.on("click", function (node , data) {' + '  self.postMessage(node.src);' +'});',
                              onMessage: function (url) { console.log(url);}
                             });
```

I have got the following log :

> console.log: rd-addon: null

Comment: did you try just [href]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
context       : contextMenu.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
```

to

```
context: contextMenu.URLContext("*"),
```

Comment: Sorry,"console.log: rd-addon: null".

Comment: wow this is crazy ok ill think about it and post a little later

Comment: Thanks for the trick, it work now :>>>context: contextMenu.URLContext("*"),
                                  contentScript : 'self.on("click", function (node , data) {' + '  self.postMessage(node.href , data );' +'});',------
(node.href) instead of (node.src).

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851835/custom-context-menu-in-firefox-with-add-on-sdk

Comment: How is using a totally incorrect selector which will show the context menu entry regardless of where you click (not just on hyperlinks) a solution to the problem?

Comment: @Damon it was "it just works" solution, it's been over a year and a half and no one else provided a solution. I did what I could for a non-sdk guy. I constantly am asking sdk devusers to please share solutions, they will be more accurate then mine. No one does, so I give people a working solution and they can hack on it till it fine tunes to what they want. Please share a solution if you can, rather then bagging on my solution. I won't be offended, and will actually be thankful if the user finds your solution more accurate and switches accepted answer to yours.

Comment: I may have sounded too harsh, my apologies. Trying to help is good, but not at every price. If a "solution" tinkers with unrelated stuff and doesn't solve the problem (but indeed introduces unwanted features), it's not of much use to be honest. Testing before stating that it works helps avoiding that. The thing is that the `URLContext` refers to the URL of the document, and `*` matches everything except local files, so in addition to not solving the problem, this _also_ shows the menu entry when it shouldn't (i.e. when not clicking a link). For a working solution, see answer by @tortway.

Comment: @Damon "Trying to help is good, but not at every price." That's cool I guess that's the opinion everyone else has because no one posts anything and posts go unreplied to for years. I'm not apart of that camp, if someone posts, i want to give them something, and they can work from there. So my solutions are not a copy paste solution but post something to guide. In my experience, whenever I asked something, people don't always give me a 1:1 solution, but I take what they give me and it's a great starting point and I eventually get to my solution. i then come back to the SO topic and share it.

Comment: So when I post something thats not 1:1 and then the question asker doesn't come back and share his final fine tuned solution, that's not on me. However it shouldn't look bad on the question asker either, it's just extra credit if he can come back. As the whole goal of the question was to get the asker the help (help doesnt mean 1:1 solution, it can mean guidance, althought 1:1 copy paste is perfect), once he got it, then good. And also I won't be offended if you downvoted, that's the right thing to do when a better solution is around, so please downvote mine and up vote @tortways to bring top.

Comment: I up voted your comment because that explains `URLContext`.

Answer (score 2):

Good for me:

```
context: [cm.URLContext("*"), cm.SelectorContext("a[href], img")],
contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
    '  self.postMessage(node.href||node.src);' +
    '});',
```

Comment: Excellent. This is among all answers (including the accepted one) **the only one** that actually addresses the problem, and the only one that actually works. The issue is indeed that `node` may or may not have `href` defined and may or may not have `src` defined (neither of which is properly documented, by the way), and the code `node.href||node.src` elegantly catches both cases.

Comment: Thank you @tortway so much for sharing an accurate solution! :) Please down vote my accepted solution so this one comes atop :)

Answer (score 0):

did you try just [href]? if not then in the contentScript change it to this:

`contentScript : 'self.on("click", function (node , data) { if (node.nodeName != "A") { return false } ' + '  self.postMessage(node.src);' +'});',`

try that if it doesnt work let me know. the solution i prefer is non-sdk and i can share that with you then

Comment: the same : "console.log: rd-addon: null"